# Break down pattern (so that I learn how it works) and add date/time

Tags: regex, powershell

I got help from you guys to extract the MAC address and UUID from textfiles using this regex pattern:

```
$Pattern = '([0-9A-Fa-f]{2}[:-]){5}([0-9A-Fa-f]{2}),\s+(\{{0,1}([0-9a-fA-F]){8}-([0-9a-fA-F]){4}-([0-9a-fA-F]){4}-([0-9a-fA-F]){4}-([0-9a-fA-F]){12}\}{0,1})'
```

Could some friendly soul break down the pattern for me to help me understand how it works?

I then need to extract date and time as well that is written in format YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS

Comment: There's plenty of tools for parsing and dissecting regex patterns online. Try https://regex101.com/ on for size

Comment: How can the year have 3 digits?

Comment: Just missed one "Y" ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the future, http://regexr.com/ is a great place to test Regex, and it will has a cheat-sheet on the left, and will explain things you highlight.

For this pattern

```
() = patttern group (orginization/grouping refrence)
[] = match anything in this character group
0-9/A-z = Match this digit/character range
{#} = match previous group # times
\s = match white space
\ = escape next character, use it as a literal or if the next character is a letter, match anything in that predefined character set.
```

So YYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS in regex is (Never use regex to validate a date however, as there are too many exceptions to make it worth while; like Feb 28. Date validation requires a calendar API of some kind)

```
[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}
```

Comment: `75:98:12` is my favorite time of day :-)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Which is technically valid in an overflow kind of way. I would only use Regex to pick up a date/time. You should ALWAYS use a calendar API to validate it (because leap days, skipped leap days, DLS, leap seconds. with that many exceptions, Regex is a horrible validation tool.)

Comment: Sorry dude, I just couldn't help myself ^_^

Comment: I did upvote you, and the validation point is important for people new to regex and think it can do everything =P

Comment: This was hard to learn.
I can match each part alone but not all at the same time.
<code>([0-9A-Fa-f]{2}[:-]){5}([0-9A-Fa-f]{2}),\s+(\{{0,1}([0-9a-fA-F]){8}-([0-9a-fA-F]){4}-([0-9a-fA-F]){4}-([0-9a-fA-F]){4}-([0-9a-fA-F]){12}\}{0,1})([0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2})([0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4})</code>